# Cauchy integration of a circle

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Evaluate: $$\int_{C(0,1)} |z-1||dz|$$

I have been trying to apply Cauchy's integration formula to the integral above but I cannot seem get it to work with the absolute values. How do those play a part in the formula?

Comment: What does $|dz|$ mean?

Comment: If there are absolute values, then this has nothing to do with Cauchy's formula anymore. This is just a plain, regular Riemann integral.

Comment: With "respect to z"? That is how it is written in the book. It is in a complex analysis book. I am just trying to get through the book as an independent study. @lhf

Comment: Ok @AlexM. that's what I was thinking but this was grouped with 4 other problems in which I had to use Cauchy's formula so I just assumed I needed it with this one also and I was trying to force it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how Cauchy's formula applies here, as the integrand appears nonanalytic.  Here's a direct approach.

$z=e^{i \phi} \implies dz = i e^{i \phi} d\phi \implies |dz| = d\phi$

Thus,

$$\oint_{|z|=1} |z-1| \, |dz| = \int_0^{2 \pi} d\phi \, \left | e^{i \phi} -1\right | = 2 \int_0^{2 \pi} d\phi \, \left | \sin{\frac{\phi}{2}} \right | = 8$$